# Throw error message if user is not active using Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, email-verification

I have field status in my users table and O want to check if status is 0 then user should not login and if 1 user should be able to login.

Here is my login code (controller is lengthy, please avoid some irrelevant code):

```
      public function fdLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $validator->messages()
        ]);
    }
    $token = "";
    try {

        // if Request has latitude and longitude
        $latFrom = $longFrom = $givenSpeciality = "";
        $locationTag = false;
        if ($request->has('lat') && $request->has('long') && $request->has('specialityKey') && !empty($request->lat) && !empty($request->long) && !empty($request->specialityKey)) {
            $latFrom = $request->lat;
            $longFrom = $request->long;
            $givenSpeciality = $request->specialityKey;
            $locationTag = true;
        }
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid username or password', 'errors' => array('Invalid username or password')));
        }

        $speciality = DB::table('specialities')
            ->join('user_facility', 'specialities.id', 'user_facility.speciality_id')
            ->where('user_facility.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->select('specialities.name', 'specialities.id')->first();
        $types = [];
        if (!empty($speciality)) {
            $types = $speciality;
        }

        $customClaims = ['exp' => Carbon::now()->addYear()->timestamp, 'specialityType' => $types];



        if (!$token = JWTAuth::claims($customClaims)->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'We can`t find an account with this credentials.'
            ], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // Something went wrong with JWT Auth.
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Failed to login, please try again.'
        ], 500);
    }

    $withInFacility['logged_in_facility'] = array();

    $currentUser = Auth::user();
    $user_id = $currentUser->id;

    if ($locationTag) {
        $userWithFacilities = $currentUser->load('facilities.facilityLocation', 'facilities.speciality.avaliableSpeciality');
        $locations = array();
        if (isset($userWithFacilities['facilities']) && count($userWithFacilities['facilities'])) {

            foreach ($userWithFacilities['facilities'] as $facility) {
                $faci = $facility->toArray();
                if (!empty($faci['facility_location']) && $faci['facility_location'] > 0) {
                    $demo = $faci['facility_location'];
                }
                if (isset($faci['speciality']) && count($faci['speciality']) > 0) {
                    $speciality = $faci['speciality'];
                    if (isset($speciality['avaliable_speciality']) && count($speciality['avaliable_speciality']) > 0) {
                        $avaliable_speciality = $speciality['avaliable_speciality'];
                        $demo['avaliable'] = $avaliable_speciality['specialty_key'];
                    }
                }
                $locations[] = $demo;
            }


           
            if (count($locations)) {

                foreach ($locations as $location) {
                    $distance = self::distance($latFrom, $longFrom, $location['lat'], $location['long']);
                    // if distance is less than 100 meter ''ll eligible to login else Log him out
                    if ($distance < config('constants.facility_radius')) {
                        if ($location['avaliable'] == $givenSpeciality) {
                            $withInFacility['logged_in_facility'] = $location;
                            $withInFacility['logged_in_facility']['radius'] = config('constants.facility_radius');
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if distance is less than 100 meter ''ll eligible to login else Log him out

                if (empty($withInFacility['logged_in_facility'])) {
                    JWTAuth::setToken($token)->invalidate();
                    return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Your are not in facility OR Your speciality did not matched with facility', 'errors' => '']);
                }
            } else {
                return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Your Facility did not have any location , please ask for administrator', 'data' => null]);
            }
        } else {
            return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'You did not have any facility , please ask for administrator', 'data' => null]);
        }
    }

    $currentUser->basicInfo = $this->userBasicInfo->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();


    $is_super_admin = DB::table('users')->select('users.is_super_admin')->where('id', $user_id)->first();

    $specialitiesAndRoles = DB::table('user_facility')
        ->leftjoin('roles', 'user_facility.role_id', 'roles.id')
        ->leftjoin('specialities', 'user_facility.speciality_id', '=', 'specialities.id')
        ->leftjoin('available_specialties', 'specialities.available_specialties_id', '=', 'available_specialties.id')
        ->where('user_facility.user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('user_facility.facility_id', 'user_facility.speciality_id', 'user_facility.is_facility_supervisor', 'user_facility.priv_key', 'user_facility.role_id', 'specialities.name', 'available_specialties.id', 'available_specialties.specialty_key')
        ->get();
    $superadmin = $is_super_admin->is_super_admin;
    $specialities = (object)$specialitiesAndRoles;

    $sp = $specialitiesAndRoles->toArray();
    $specialty_key = "";
    if (!empty($sp)) {
        $specialty_key = $sp[0]->specialty_key;

    }

    $fac_privs = array();
    if (!empty($sp)) {
        foreach ($sp as $s) {
            $s = (array)$s;

            $s['priv_list'] = Helpers::get_checked_privs($s);
            $fac_privs[] = $s;
        }
    }

    if (count($withInFacility['logged_in_facility'])) {
        $withInFacilityObj = (object)$withInFacility['logged_in_facility'];
    } else {
        $withInFacilityObj = NULL;
    }

    $response = ['is_super_admin' => $superadmin, 'facilities' => $fac_privs, 'logged_in_facility' => $withInFacilityObj];

    if ($superadmin == 1) {
        $response['priv_ist'] = Helpers::get_priv_list();
    }
    $speciality = $this->speciality;
    if ($speciality) {
        $user = DB::table('verify_users')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();


        DB::table('verify_users')->insert([
            'token' => $token,
            'user_id' => $user_id,

        ]);
        if ($specialty_key == 'medical_doctor') {

            $md_db = DB::connection('doctorDB');
            $user = $md_db->table('auth_token')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

            if ($user) {
                $md_db->table('auth_token')->where('id', $user->id)->update([
                    'token' => $token,
                    'isValid' => 1,

                ]);
            } else {
                $md_db->table('auth_token')->insert([
                    'token' => $token,
                    'isValid' => 1,
                    'user_id' => $user_id
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    $user_data = $this->GetUserInfo();

    unset($currentUser['facilities']);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'Login successfully',
        'data' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'userData' => $currentUser,
            'userInfo' => $user_data,
            'privileges' => $response,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

This is my whole controller of login I am not using Laravel built-in authentication, I have created my own login based on my project requirement, and I want to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are not checking when you get the user info. I am not sure what is your purpose but may be this code will help you.

```
$currentUser = Auth::user();
if($currentUser->status == 0){
    Auth::logout();
    return response()->json([
        'status' => false,
        'message' => 'Failed to login, Access forbidden.',
    ], 403);
}
```